# PHP die stops everything. What else can I use?

Tags: php

I hope this is the last time I have to bother you good people.  I'm a newbie hack who is working on a unique hit counter for each page of a web site.  I seem to have it working properly but after the first time when it hits and adds the IP to the file it stops the whole page from loading on refresh or coming back.  I know the problem is with the 'die' statement which ends the loop of checking for the IP.  I have also tried 'break' and 'exit' but the same thing happens.  I have searched for anything else but I can't find anything.  Is there a way of getting out of the php code without stopping everything else from loading?  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

//  Declare string names
        $ip_file = "ip_index.txt"; 

//  get ip address of user      
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip_handle = fopen($ip_file, "r");

    while (!feof($ip_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($ip_handle);
    $ip = trim($line_of_text);

    if ($user_ip==$ip){

        die();
        }   
    }
    $count_file = 'count_index.txt';

//  read contents of count.txt
    $count_file = "count_index.txt";

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $handle = fopen($count_file, "r");
    $old_count=fgets($handle);
    fclose($handle);

//  write contents of count.txt

    $fp = fopen($count_file, 'ab');
    if (false === $fp) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
    }

    $handle = fopen($count_file, "w");  
    $new_count = $old_count +1;
    fwrite($handle, $new_count);
    fclose($handle);

//  write new IP to ip.txt file

    $fp = fopen($ip_file, 'r');
    if (false === $fp) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
    }

    $handle = fopen($ip_file, 'a+');    
    $w_user_ip=$user_ip . "\n";

    fwrite($handle, $w_user_ip);
    fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: You could wrap it in a function/functions and use return.

Comment: I think you're looking for `continue`

Comment: what about using continue; instead

Comment: Why are you opening each file twice? And why don't you ever close `$fp`?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the 'continue' and although that allows the rest of the page to load it also hits the counter and ads the IP each time I hit refresh, kinda defeating the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't exit the whole script when you find a match, just exit the loop. Set a variable that allows you to skip over the code that increments the unique hit counter.

```
$ip_exists = false;
while (!feof($ip_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($ip_handle);
    $ip = trim($line_of_text);

    if ($user_ip==$ip){
        $ip_exists = true;
        break;
    }   
}

if (!$ip_exists) {
    // Update all the files
    ...
}
```

Comment: I used a slight variation of this and solved my problem.  Apparently I wasn't very good at stating the problem.  I think some of the others were saying something similar but I couldn't wrap my ole man, novice head around them.  This one I understood.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. You can reverse the condition of the `if` block and then just wrap the remaining code in the braces.

eg

```
if ($user_ip != $ip) {
    $count_file = 'count_index.txt';

    // read contents of count.txt
    $count_file = "count_index.txt";

    // ... etc

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have:

```
if ($user_ip==$ip){
    die();
}
```

Put everything you don't want to run if the IPs are the same in an `else{}` block

Comment: Thanks.  I was already working on the @Barmar condition above and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
....

if ($user_ip != $ip) {
    $count_file = 'count_index.txt';

//  read contents of count.txt
    $count_file = "count_index.txt";

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $handle = fopen($count_file, "r");
    $old_count=fgets($handle);
    fclose($handle);

//  write contents of count.txt

    $fp = fopen($count_file, 'ab');
    if (false === $fp) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
    }

    $handle = fopen($count_file, "w");  
    $new_count = $old_count +1;
    fwrite($handle, $new_count);
    fclose($handle);

//  write new IP to ip.txt file

    $fp = fopen($ip_file, 'r');
    if (false === $fp) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
    }

    $handle = fopen($ip_file, 'a+');    
    $w_user_ip=$user_ip . "\n";

    fwrite($handle, $w_user_ip);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is included by other code you can use `return`:

```
if ($user_ip==$ip){
    return;
}
```

This will stop further execution of your script but code which is including wont die.

If on the other hand you want to terminate the while loop only then `break` is what you need (what issue did you have when using it?)

```
if ($user_ip==$ip){
    break;
}
```

Comment: Return doesn't work in this case at it appears the code is procedural.

Comment: @kinghfb Procedural code will still return if it's used as an `include`. Don't think this is what the asker meant but I mentioned that as the question was slightly unclear.